# Unable to disable a Visualforce Override for standard buttons

Tags: visualforce, button-overrides, bug

I have installed an HR managed package, but I don't want to use their Visualforce pages on some objects -- I would prefer to use the standard Salesforce record detail page. I have edited the standard New, Edit and View buttons so that they no longer use the Visualforce Page, but rather the "Standard Page". However I am seeing 2 problems now:

1. Although I can now see the standard Salesforce UI, I still cannot do any inline editing of the record detail page. The pencil icon is gone and I can only edit the record by clicking the "Edit" button.
2. In Setup -> Object Manager -> Object -> Buttons & Actions, I have edited each button to use the "Standard Page",  but it still lists the Visualforce Page. See screenshot below.

[image: You can see that even though I set the button override to "Standard Page", it lists it in setup as being set to the Visualforce Pages]

How do I fully revert back to the Salesforce standard UI so that I can do inline editing on the page? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

May be you can try through url

https://yoursalesforceinstance.com/apex/visualforcepagename?nooverride=1

Comment: No, that is not ideal and will not fit my use-case.

Comment: This is not a link-only answer; the link is an illustration. While the asker has indicated it's not a good solution fit, it is an attempt at a genuine answer.